How do I make cards inside a container blurred but not the first card inside of the container?
So to breakdown what I am trying to achieve:
I want all the cards inside of a container to be blurred besides the very first card, until you actually hover on the next card in the container to which it should then blur all of the cards besides the next card you are hovering on.

I have managed to make the cards all blur and the one i am hovering on will unblur, but that means that when not hovering on the container they are all blurred. This is not what I am trying to achieve.

I have put a snippet of the structurte of the list of cards I have below:
<ul class="exp__list">
    <li class="exp__list__item">
        <div class="exp__card">
            <div class="card__header">
                <h2>2024 - PRESENT</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="card__content">
                <h3 class="card__title">Junior Web Developer</h3>
                <p class="card__info">Build and maintain a website for Dynamic Roofing
                    Solutions Ltd. Working closely with the directors to fulfill their
                    development needs.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>HTML</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>CSS</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>JavaScript</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>Google Scripts</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- More cards here -->
</ul>

.exp__card:hover {
        background-color: #00d20013;
        border: -1px solid var(--text-primary-color);
    }

.exp__list .exp__card {
        filter: blur(3px);
        opacity: .99;
    }

.exp__card:hover {
        filter: blur(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }


If you want it so that when you hover over a card, it becomes unblurred until another card is hovered, you can use JavaScript and add a blurred class to all cards except the one that is hovered over:

Note not hovering any card will blur all cards except the first one



const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.exp__card');

// blur all cards except the first one
cards.forEach((card, index) => {
  if (index !== 0) {
    card.classList.add('blurred');
  }
});

// unblur the card that is hovered and blur the others
cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    cards.forEach(c => c.classList.add('blurred'));
    card.classList.remove('blurred');
  });

  card.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    cards.forEach((c, index) => {
      if (index !== 0) {
        c.classList.add('blurred');
      } else {
        c.classList.remove('blurred');
      }
    });
  });
});
.exp__card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.blurred {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
<div class="exp__card">Card</div>
<div class="exp__card">Card</div>
<div class="exp__card">Card</div>
<div class="exp__card">Card</div>
<div class="exp__card">Card</div>
<div class="exp__card">Card</div>




Thanks! The javascript method worked for me! I assume the css method above which works in the snippet did not work for me due to something happening in my cascade. But anyways this worked for me.

To expand on this, is there a way to make the hover effect snap back to the first card when not hovering on any cards?

I thought this was the behavior you were after. I will edit it right now.

@CallumLuxford Please see the updated snippet

Perfect m-sarabi! Thank you for the javascript solution. I had thought about using Js but I was sure there was a way to solve this in css, and although there will be this just seemed to have done the trick and logically makes more sense to me. Thank you! :)

Thank you I have checked this, all works great now I have to find a solution for scrolling over the cards on mobile XD But thanks for this

There is only one issue I have noticed with this and that is that if you hover after the second element Just between the element and the next element, the effect jumps to the top element before you hover on the next element.

You might try:
.exp__list__item:not(:hover) .exp__card:first-child {
  filter: blur(0) !important;
}

Here's a snippet to test this


.exp__card:hover {
  background-color: #00d20013;
  border: -1px solid var(--text-primary-color);
}

.exp__list .exp__card {
  filter: blur(3px);
  opacity: .99;
}

.exp__card:hover {
  filter: blur(0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.exp__list__item:not(:hover) .exp__card:first-child {
  filter: blur(0) !important;
}
<ul class="exp__list">
  <li class="exp__list__item">
    <div class="exp__card">
      <div class="card__header">
        <h2>2024 - PRESENT</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="card__content">
        <h3 class="card__title">Junior Web Developer</h3>
        <p class="card__info">Build and maintain a website for Dynamic Roofing
                                                    Solutions Ltd. Working closely with the directors to fulfill their
                                                    development needs.</p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>HTML</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>CSS</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>JavaScript</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>Google Scripts</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="exp__card">
      <div class="card__header">
        <h2>2024 - PRESENT</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="card__content">
        <h3 class="card__title">Junior Web Developer</h3>
        <p class="card__info">Build and maintain a website for Dynamic Roofing
                                                    Solutions Ltd. Working closely with the directors to fulfill their
                                                    development needs.</p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>HTML</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>CSS</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>JavaScript</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>Google Scripts</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>




Hi there, Thank you for replying to this question. This did not seem to work in my case, it just took off the blur effect from the entire container of cards? Rather than just the first child. And hovering does nothing

If you scroll down you will see two cards. The first one is never blurred until you hover the second one, wasn't this your request?

Hi Thomas yes, I did see that. And I see this works, but for unknown reasons, maybe something inside of my cascade., it does not work in my current poject.

I'm unsure why.. I just copy pasted your example

I did not want to paste the entire code because I'm sure you are not allowed to do that on her, otherwise someone may have spotted the issue from there. But for refernece I do have the cards inside of another container which is a scrollable container with more styling. Maybe something to do with the styling there. Not sure I can replicate the problem though. however the javascript method worked

Ah ok, anyways, good luck with your project :)
